# Display non-english characters with TCPDF

Tags: php, pdf, tcpdf

I am using the TCPDF library to export Album / Catalog Release information for a music site, the Album consists of songs labels that could be in English, chinese or any other language, I am having a problem to print the non-English character correctly inside the tcpdf. Some points I would like to tell.

1. I am using `Zend framework 1.12`.
2. Database Connection collation `utf8` .
3. Table field collation `utf8_unicode_ci` .

My scenario is that the information is coming from the database and I use a view to display information related to the album in a specific format along with the `HTML`. The release name is in Chinese `奥马尔阿斯拉姆`, I tried all the options by searching on stackoverflow which were related to setting the font and changing character collation while initializing the TCPDF object, but whenever I print it displays the name like this `Ã¥Â¥Â¥Ã©Â©Â¬Ã¥Â°Â”Ã©Â˜Â¿Ã¦Â–Â¯Ã¦Â‹Â` i tried to `utf8_encode()` and `utf8_decode()` around the Release Name inside the HTML but nothing helps.

Another is an example is with the Latin characters where the name of the album is `Extraña EP` and when printed inside the pdf it displays it like `ExtranÌƒa EP`.

Here is the HTML I use inside my view.

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <img src="/images/release_details.png">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
            <table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="release_table">
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">CATALOG #:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->Catalog?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">RELEASE NAME:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->Name?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">RELEASE TYPE:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$releaseType?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">UPC CODE:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->UPCCode?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">NUMBER OF SONGS:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->TracksQty?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">PRIMARY ARTIST:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top"
                        class="data"><?=$this->release->PrimaryArtist?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">LABEL:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->LabelName?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">MAIN GENRE:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->MainGenre?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">GENRE:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->Genre?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">(C):</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top"
                        class="data"><?=$this->release->CLine . " " . $this->release->CYear?></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">(P):</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top"
                        class="data"><?=$this->release->PLine . " " . $this->release->PYear?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php if ($this->release->Howlong > 0 && $this->release->EffectiveDate > 0) {?>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">EXCLUSIVE DATE:</td>
                        <td align="right" valign="top"
                            class="data"><?=$this->release->EffectiveDate?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }?>

                <tr>
                    <td align="left" valign="top" class="label">RELEASE DATE:</td>
                    <td align="right" valign="top" class="data"><?=$this->release->ReleaseDate?></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="center" valign="middle">

            <img src="/images/symphonic_logo.png"/>

        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

And here is the code where i call this view before i send the content to print in the pdf.

```
require_once APPLICATION_PATH . 'library/tcpdf/tcpdf.php';
$pdf = new TCPDF("L", "mm", "A4", false, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 11, '', true);
$pdf->SetMargins(1, -1, -1, false);
//$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 12);
//whole TCPDF's settings goes here
$this->view->songs = $releaseSongs;
$this->view->release = $releasInformation;
$htmlcontent = $this->view->render('exportpdf.phtml');

// output the HTML content
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->deletePage($pages + 1);
$pdf->Output($filename, 'D');
exit();
```

Comment: I see `ISO-8859-1` right on line #2...

Comment: Yeah that's because i was trying different options and the option UTF-8 was tried already AND using `$pdf = new TCPDF("L", "mm", "A4", TRUE, 'UTF-8', false);` outputs the characters `Extraña EP` as `Extran?a EP` and `奥马尔阿斯拉姆` as  `???????`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here are the few things that i did to correct my code.

1. used the custom fonts option to add the Ms arial unicode true type font.
2. I was adding the style tag with css classes where i was setting the font family inside the view which resulted in the garbage characters in case of non-english characters. This was the main mistake.

Here is he final working code

```
require_once(APPLICATION_PATH . 'library/tcpdf/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF("L", "mm", "A4", TRUE, 'utf-8', false);
$fontname   =   TCPDF_FONTS::addTTFfont(APPLICATION_PATH.'/../library/tcpdf/fonts/ARIALUNI.TTF','TrueTypeUnicode', '', 32);
$pdf->AddFont($fontname);
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont($fontname, '', 12, '', true);
$pdf->SetMargins(1, -1, -1, false);
//$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 12);
//whole TCPDF's settings goes here


$htmlcontent = $this->view->render('exportpdf.phtml');

// output the HTML content
$pdf->AddPage();
$pdf->writeHTML($htmlcontent, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->deletePage($pages + 1);
$pdf->Output($filename, 'D');
```

Answer (score 0):

The collation doesn't help if you want to work with UTF-8, it only determines the sorting order. What you propably need is to set the charset of the database connection, this you should set before you do any query/inserts:

```
// tells the mysqli connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$db = new mysqli($dbHost, $dbUser, $dbPassword, $dbName);
$db->set_charset('utf8');

// tells the pdo connection to deliver UTF-8 encoded strings.
$dsn = "mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8";
$db = new PDO($dsn, $dbUser, $dbPassword);
```

Reading and writing your data with this connection, you should be able to set the encoding of your PDF to UTF-8.

Comment: Yes you are right i have these settings defined in the ini file as `database.params.charset  = "utf8"`for the database connection and is loaded at the time of bootstrap.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam - Then i would check whether your HTML page is correctly encoded, this [W3C checker](http://validator.w3.org/i18n-checker/) could give you further hints.

Comment: lol @martinstoeckli may be you missed my answer  that i posted before your reply , i have fixed it already , thanks for the concern tho.